# WebStorm - Hide 'template literals' highlighting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ide, webstorm

I've just switched from Atom to WebStorm as development platform. I'm rather new to Angular and JavaScript, but having a fully fledged IDE seems a bit better for me to figure out where errors are coming from.

I'm experiencing one little annoyance... I can't seem to find how to disable the multiline (template literal, I believe it's called) highlighting of the backticks (`). This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of highlight]

Could someone please help me figure out how I can disable it?

Comment: 1) So .. you just want to remove that green background color? 2) AFAIK you cannot disable it just there .. it will affect all similar places (where such functionality is used) -- is that OK?

Comment: Yeah it's that green 'background' color, that is displayed between the two backticks (`). You sure there is no way to disable it? I don't mind sacrificing the other functionality with it. @LazyOne

Comment: My #2 means: that background color can be removed .. but it will also be removed from other similar places. No actual functionality will be lost -- you will just loose an indication of such places (sometimes it's very helpful to see what is going on .. as in some cases where user configures IDE in a wrong way (accidentally or by mistake) such color allows to diagnose the issue straight away instead of wondering for eternity for possible reasons)

Comment: @LazyOne Gotcha! Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! You can disable this by going to the Preferences > Editor > General > Injected Language Fragment > un-tick the 'background color'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me hours

Comment: @DemvenWeir glad I could help, bud.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**

Go to

```
Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Code > Injected language fragment
```

and untick the `Background` option:

[Editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UHsa.png)